# How to mark a given location as obstacle

Tags: ros, navigation, pioneer, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now i have a robot that stops when it detects a person.  I need to be able to mark a coordinate as obstacles, even though it still is not an obstacle.  This is because im predicting the behavior of the person so i need to mark as obstacles the path i think it will walk.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?
Can i just add an obstacle on the obstacle topic? and if so how can i manage this?
Also i found out you can change the laserscan to add the new arbitrary obstacle here is this a possibility?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93201/how-to-mark-a-given-location-as-obstacle/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-23**:
Consider discussing this at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ros-sig-navigation , the navigation SIG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Hydromedusa you could create a costmap2d layer that increases cost along the predicted path of the moving obstacle.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-23**:
right now im using fuerte, is there a way to do it in fuerte? Thanks

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-23**:
For costmap2d layers you'll need Hydro. I assume there is a way to achieve it in Fuerte as well, but I'm afraid I have no idea how.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-29**:
@Hendrik *SeveQ* Wiese  @KruseT instead of using a layered costmap is it possible to just "change" the obstacle topic to add new obstacles?

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-05-30**:
i would like to know how to use this to detect dynamic targets